# Using value_counts with conditions (datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filter, boolean

I am trying to keep only true values of my column, here is the code and output:

```
 self.mask = self.data['Date'].apply(self.in_range, args=(user_start, user_stop))

 def evaluate_error(self):
        err_count = self.data.groupby([self.mask, 'Résultat']).size()
        print(err_count)
        print('')

output: 

Date   Résultat
False  0           85
       51           1
       55           1
       656          2
True   0           10
       55           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter values after `groupby.size`:

```
err_count = self.data.groupby([self.mask, 'Résultat']).size().loc[True]
```

Or before, then is possible use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
err_count = self.data.loc[self.mask, 'Résultat'].value_counts()
```

---

```
err_count = self.data.loc[self.mask, 'Résultat'].groupby('Résultat').size()
```